# How to increase COMMITTED_CPUS quota?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I tried to purchase additional committed use discount in GCP but I got this error.

> Quota 'COMMITTED_CPUS' exceeded. Limit: 75.0 in region asia-southeast1.

Previously, I already purchase some CPU and memory successfully. I tried to search in [Quota page](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas?location=asia-southeast1) but I can't find anything with `COMMITTED_CPUS` or `75` limits. Digging to `commitments` metric only purchase quota not cpu quota.
[Commitments Quota](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0RCy8.png)

I also try this command but still can't find it.

> gcloud compute project-info describe --project "project_name"

I can't purchase it both in console and using this command.

> gcloud compute commitments create asia-southeast-1y-3 --plan 12-month --region asia-southeast1 --resources=MEMORY=106GB,VCPU=36

Comment: answered in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53736973/how-to-increase-committed-cpus-quota/53740623

Answer (score 1):

As stated by Lee [on this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53736973/how-to-increase-committed-cpus-quota/53740623)

"I've confront this issue before. I can provide you some SOP for solving this:

File a new case to increase your COMMITMENTS quota in the same region you’re seeing the problem in order to address the problem in an automated way. Each COMMITMENTS increase also increases COMMITTED_CPUS to the current quota of CPUS in the region.

To be very specific, if you need an increase for COMMITTED_CPUS, the only way is to request an increase for COMMITMENTS. To request quota for Commitments, follow these instructions:

1. Go to the Quota Increase page in the Google Cloud Platform Console
2. Expand the Quota type dropdown menu and select All quotas.
3. Expand the Metric dropdown menu.
4. Click on None to hide all quotas and then type Commitments in the search box to search for Commitments quota.
5. Select Commitments from the list.
6. Select the checkbox next to Commitments for the desired region and click the Edit Quotas button.
7. If prompted, fill in your first and last name, and phone number. Click Next.
8. Fill out the request form and click Next.
9. Click Submit Request to submit your request.

Once your request is received, it takes about 2 business days. Hope this helps!